# Why isn't the first character uppercase?

Tags: java, string, char, uppercase, lowercase

I have found syntax that is supposed to change the first character from a lowercase letter to an uppercase letter.

For some reason my program won't! When I type a 'm' instead of 'M'.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter two characters: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String twoChar = input.nextLine();

    if(twoChar.length() > 2 || twoChar.length() <= 1){
        System.out.println("You must enter exactly two characters");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    char ch = Character.toUpperCase(twoChar.charAt(0));

    if(twoChar.charAt(0) == 'M'){
        if(twoChar.charAt(1) == '1'){
            System.out.println("Mathematics Freshman");
        }else if(twoChar.charAt(1) == '2'){
            System.out.println("Mathematics Sophomore");
        }else if(twoChar.charAt(1) == '3'){
            System.out.println("Mathematics Junior");
        }else if(twoChar.charAt(1) == '4'){
            System.out.println("Mathematics Senior");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because you make a copy of the character that is upper-cased, then test against the original character. Test against the copy `ch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(twoChar.charAt(0) == 'M'){
```

use

```
if(ch == 'M'){
```

You are getting the uppercased character, but then not using it.

Comment: Thanks, it's all fixed now

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the upper case version of the character to a variable `ch`, and then you are not checking `ch`; you are checking the character in the string again. That character is the same as it was before: it is not changed.

So instead of checking:

```
if (twoChar.charAt(0) == 'M') {
```

check:

```
if (ch == 'M') {
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Not using the local variable

You aren't using the `char ch` you uppercased here,

```
char ch = Character.toUpperCase(twoChar.charAt(0));
if(twoChar.charAt(0) == 'M'){
```

you might fix it by using the *local variable* `ch` like

```
char ch = Character.toUpperCase(twoChar.charAt(0));
if (ch == 'M') {
```

or by placing the `toUpperCase` call in-line like

```
// char ch = Character.toUpperCase(twoChar.charAt(0));
if (Character.toUpperCase(twoChar.charAt(0)) == 'M') {
```

or using a logical-or like

```
char ch = twoChar.charAt(0);
if (ch == 'M' || ch == 'm') {
```